# Simulink transfer fcn with matrix as parameters

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink

Let's say I want to model this equation (electrical motor, 6 phases):

*Vs = Rs*Is + d/dt*(Ls*Is)*

where all variables are matrix, so:

*Vs = [va1 vb1 vc1 va2 vb2 vc2]'* (column vector)

*Is = [ia1 ib1 ic1 ia2 ib2 ic2]'* (column vector)

*Ls* and *Rs* are 6x6 matrix (constants)

From my point of view the Vs is the input vector and Is is the output vector so I need to rearrange the equation.

I have seen that is not possible in Simulink to feed the Transfer Fcn block with matrix, at least not for a multiple input multiple output system.

Is there a way to realize this on Simulink still using the matrix *Ls* and *Rs* without "unpacking" the equation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would re-arrange your equations in state-space form and use the [State-Space](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/statespace.html) block, which is better suited for matrix equations.

Another option is to use basic Simulink blocks, such as [Integrator](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/integrator.html) and [Gain](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/gain.html) blocks, with vectorized inputs. I am not 100% sure this will work, but reasonably confident.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I manage to use the state-space block and it worked but in the meanwhile I changed the model (added another input) and now I can't re-arrange the system in the state-space form. I will try now with integrator and gain blocks and see if I can find a way to realize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the product block with matrices inside Matlab so there should be no problem. It's also possible to use integrator/derivative block (though it's better to avoid using derivative if possible) with a vector input so if you can put your equation with Is as an output there should be no problem.
You can put 2 multiply blocks with your matrices as inputs and the vector you need and you will get a vector for the output like you want.